# Access Task Scheduler in Windows Server 2003 and send email if scheduled task fails using C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-2003-webserver

I am trying to create a program that will automatically keep track of the windows task scheduler and will notify me via email if a ny of the scheduled task fails to launch. I am C# as the programming language. I've checked various references but haven't been able to achieve this. Can anyone please provide me any reference or suggestion as to how I can access the log and check if any task launch has failed?

Here's my code:

```
        EventLog demoLog = new EventLog();
        demoLog.Source="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational";
        try
        {
            EventLogEntryCollection entries = demoLog.Entries;
            foreach (EventLogEntry entry in entries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Level: {0}", entry.EntryType);
                Console.WriteLine("Event id: {0}", entry.InstanceId);
                Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", entry.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", entry.Source);
                Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", entry.TimeGenerated);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you tried and what fails. Do you have some error? What are you using to get the scheduled tasks?

Comment: Yeah I have the code and when I am executing it, it gives me Inaccessible Logs : Security Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/882df3d5-9a9b-437b-a6ab-e09873ce6ece/cant-access-event-log-for-tasks?forum=csharplanguage).

They use there an `EventlogReader` to get the information. Maybe it help. I managed to read the events from my computer using it.

Comment: It works for me as well @Gilad Green but can you help me in finding the time an event occurred?

Comment: @Rajdeep Nandi - It has a property TimeCreated that by the MSDN documentation is the time where the log record was created (makes sense :) ).
[Here is the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventrecord(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yeah now I've found out the way...@Gilad Green